# New Rails 3.1.3 + Datamapper routing assets issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-datamapper

I am eager to try out DataMapper for a new Rails project. I created my project using the following command:

```
rails new project_name -m http://datamapper.org/templates/rails.rb
```

I decided to test out my application by running:

```
rails server
```

When I go to the generic home page that is created, I can't see any images. I get an error stating:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/rails.png")
```

If I create any other scaffolds and visit those pages, I get similar errors about the stylesheets or javascript not found. I double checked to ensure that a regular Activerecord-rails application worked (which it did). I'm rather puzzled. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

Comment: Why is it `"/asets/rails.png"` instead of `"/assets/rails.png"`?

Comment: Oops! I meant assets ;) I'll change that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, DataMapper's Rails template completely replaces the standard `Gemfile` with their own, which doesn't include any of the asset handling stuff (it also removes a handful of other things like jQuery support, TestUnit, ActionMailer...).

You'll want to add these back in to your `Gemfile` after setting up the new application:

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Per Frederick's suggestion below, you'll also want to add this into your `config/application.rb` file:

```
require 'sprockets/railtie'
```

[I opened an Issue](https://github.com/datamapper/datamapper.github.com/issues/28) and [submitted a pull request](https://github.com/datamapper/datamapper.github.com/pull/29) to fix this.

**Update**: As of 1/5/2012, this is now fixed. The template behaves nearly identical to a standard Rails 3.1 app with the only change being ActiveRecord being replaced with DataMapper. Assets/jQuery support now works.

Comment: it also changes `require 'rails/all'` in application.rb to an explicit list of frameworks but misses off sprockets, which is used to deliver the asset stuff in 3.1. Adding `require 'sprockets/railtie'` to application.rb should help.

Comment: Thank you Dylan and Frederick =)